# Citing a general fact but applying it to a specific point I'm making in a sentence

Tags: citations

Here are two sentences from a paper I'm writing:

> In addition to being context specific, competencies try to describe what a person needs to succeed in a context at a useful level of abstraction. This point is perhaps best illustrated by contrasting competencies to its more concrete evolutionary predecessor job analysis (Scott & Reynolds, 2010).

The first sentence is something a point that I, the author, am making.

The more general fact that 'job analysis is an evolutionary predecessor to competencies' is from Scott and Reynolds (2010).

It's a bit ambiguous: you could read the sentence as it is Scott and Reynolds (2010) who are saying that the "point could be well illustrated by contrasting" which is imprecise.

To remove ambiguity, I could write something like:

> Job analysis is the evolutionary predecessor to competencies (Scott & Reynolds, 2010). The former is more concrete and the latter more abstract. Comparing the two is useful to illustrate what competencies are.

But it really breaks up the flow of the paragraph, creating a more awkward reading experience for the reader.

Is having the sort of ambiguity of the first example, for the sake of flow and narrative, bad or wrong citation practice?

Edit: So my question here is about clarity and explicitness of citations. How clear should a text be as to what is attributed to whom? When does it get too sloppy or unclear who said what?

Comment: I do not think this site is about writing a paper, not in the sense supposed by this question.

Comment: @Alchimista my question is about citation conventions, tried to clarify with an edit

Comment: What Scott & Reynolds did? They introduced/developed something called "competencies" (it is even not clear competencies is a model/system/etc)? If so you can put a comma after it, and then say "competencies, the latter approach discussed in Ref. #. But this is nothing about conventions.

Comment: I can only say I find the second version much clearer and better to read.